# How can I change the default PowerShell error for when a command needs elevation?

Tags: powershell, function, error-handling, windows-11, elevation

I have a lot of code in a PowerShell script that are mix of commands that need elevation to run and commands that don't, those that need elevation show errors in PowerShell console like:

```
"You don't have enough permissions to perform the requested operation"
```

and

```
 "Requested registry access is not allowed."
```

is there a way to globally suppress only the kinds of errors that PowerShell shows due to lack of necessary privileges?

I thought about a function that checks for elevation and performs actions based on the result, like this:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-function-to-determine-elevation-of-powershell-console/

```
Function Test-IsAdmin

{    
   
 $identity = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()

 $principal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $identity

 $principal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)

   }
```

and

```
if(-NOT (Test-IsAdmin))

   { write-host "Skipping Admin command" }

else { $code }
```

but I don't know how to apply it globally to the whole script, so that commands that don't need elevation run, and those that need elevation show a custom message or skip that part silently.

another thing that can help my situation would be to find out if a PowerShell command needs elevation before actually running it and causing it to show errors in console due to lack of privileges.

Comment: Use `Try....Catch` constructs to carry out commands as it will let you perform additional sscript actions on error. But why not just write your script with a section that only gets carried out if script is elevated?

Comment: @Scepticalist Thanks, so far I used that `Test-IsAdmin` function to take care of the elevation errors, had to use it a couple of times in the script, but I'm still looking for the answer to my questions, specially last one about finding out if a command needs elevation before running it. maybe something like `-WhatIF` but not sure if that's possible or even exists yet.

Comment: It doesn't exist and is unlikely to. You can write scripts properly to catch errors like that. e.g. `Try { Thiscommand -ErrorAction Stop };Catch { Write-Host "Command not performed because: " + $_.Exception.Message }

Comment: True, but I only want to suppress the errors related to privileges escalation, not any other kinds of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that errors stemming from a lack of privileges *typically* - but not necessarily - involve a [`System.UnauthorizedAccessException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.UnauthorizedAccessException) or [`System.Security.SecurityException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecurityException) .NET exception behind the scenes, whose name is then reflected as part of the `.FullyQualifiedErrorId` property of the resulting PowerShell error record, which is of type [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord).

Assuming that this applies to all errors you care about, you can use a (rarely used anymore) [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement as follows:

```bash
trap {
  if ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -match 'UnauthorizedAccessException|SecurityException') { 
    Write-Warning "Skipping admin command ($($_.InvocationInfo.Line.Trim()))"
    continue # Suppress the original error and continue.
  }
  # If the error was created with `throw`, emit the error and abort processing.
  # SEE CAVEAT BELOW.
  elseif ($_.Exception.WasThrownFromThrowStatement) { break }
  # Otherwise: emit the error and continue.
}

# ... your script
```

**Caveat**:

- If your script *implicitly* raises *script*-terminating errors - via `-ErrorAction Stop` or `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` - the above solution in effect turns them into *statement*-terminating errors and *continues execution* (only *explicit* script-terminating errors created with a [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) statement are recognized as such in the code above, and result in the script getting aborted).
- Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.2.x, there is *no* way to *generally* discover whether a given error is (a) *non-terminating*, (b) *statement*-terminating or (c) *script*-terminating (fatal).

  - See [GitHub issue #4781](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4781) for a proposal to add properties to [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`] to allow such discovery in the future.

Comment: @zerogainer, please see my update: I've added `SecurityException`, which is what is reported in the case of the image you link to. The general problem, as noted in the answer, is that it's hard to anticipate all error variations that can stem from the same root cause.